# com.sun.proxy.$proxy0 cannot be cast to XXX

Tags: java, rmi

I was writing a RMI application. I have a method on the server side, which returns an `ArrayList<User>` and `User` is a class I defined myself. The code is like: `list = obj.getList(); System.out.println(list.get(0).getName());`, and this line generated an exception of "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to User". Can anybody help me about that?

Comment: Doesn't it need to be an `ArrayList<SomeRemoteInterface>`?

Answer (score 3):

If `User` is an exported remote object, as it seems to be, it appears in the client as the remote interface it implements, not as the implementation class.

So that's what you must cast it to. In this case that means declaring your List as `List<UserInterface>`, where `UserInterface` is the name of the remote interface. Adjust to suit.

Comment: Yes this exactly where I made mistakes! This is a rather complicated application and it got many interfaces. I just forgot that there was an interface for `User` too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this problem before.
I added `extends Remote` at the end of `public interface nameOfYourInterface`. It worked for me.